# Sending data to controller using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that contains different fields for user to fill in and also allow user to attach image. Below is my code to send data to the controller, I can see the image in my controller but I am not sure how to access rest of form data in controller:

```
$(function () {
    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {

        var $form = $(this);
        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#File").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) { data.append("File", files[0]); }
        else {
            common.showNotification('warning', 'Please select file to upload.', 'top', 'right');
            return false;
        }


        var options = {
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: false


        };
        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {

            $('#ProdList').html(data);



        });
        return false;
    };
    $("form[data-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);
});
```

My controller :

```
public ActionResult Create(PostViewProduct postProduct)
        {
//code......
}
```

PostViewProduct model shows only image fields with data rest showing null:
[image]

Do I have to add each field using formdata.append() or is there better way to send all the data to controller and then access the data in controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
```

instead of `var data = new FormData();`

Answer (score 0):

Try following, this will put the data in right format if all input is within the form.

```
data = $form.serialize();
```

Comment: tried this , now all fields including image showing null.

Comment: Are you right they have the right naming attribute on your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to send the files in FormData along with other form element data.

```
$(function () {          
    var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {

        var fdata = new FormData();

        $('input[name="Image"]').each(function (a, b) {
            var fileInput = $('input[name="Image"]')[a];
            if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
                var file = fileInput.files[0];
                fdata.append("Image", file);
            }
        });

        // You can update the jquery selector to use a css class if you want
        $("input[type='text'").each(function (x, y) {
            fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });

        var frmUrl = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: frmUrl,
            data: fdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
     $("form[data-ajax='true']").submit(ajaxFormSubmit);

});
```

Assuming your view model has a property called Image of type HttpPostedFileBase for accepting the posted file and your form has an input for that

```
public class YourViewModel
{
   public HttpPostedFileBase Image { set;get;}
   //Your other existing properties
}
```

and your form has an file input tag with name "Image".

```
<input type="file" name="Image" />
```